# most efficient way to sort two sorted array into new sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting

I am trying to sort two int arrays into a new int array in ascending order.

I wrote it like this and it sorted everything but the last element in textArr and I couldn't figure out why...

```
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(i < textArr.length && j < binaryArr.length) {
    if(textArr[i] < binaryArr[j]) {
        mergeArr[k] = textArr[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        mergeArr[k] = binaryArr[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

**I looked around and found a solution that added two new while loops but I honestly do not know what those second two while loops are doing.  I'd also like to know if this is the most efficient way to sort two arrays into a third sorted array?**  Thanks for any help, I'm very new to java and would like to learn correctly and obviously I want to learn what I'm actually writing too!

```
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(i < textArr.length && j < binaryArr.length) {
    if(textArr[i] < binaryArr[j]) {
        mergeArr[k] = textArr[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        mergeArr[k] = binaryArr[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
while(i < textArr.length) {
    mergeArr[k] = textArr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
```

Comment: It's called a merge.

Comment: I get that just didn't understand what exactly those last two while loops were doing.

Comment: The best way to see what's going on is to step through the algorithm with a debugger.

Comment: I understand now based on what you said below Paul, thank you!  If you put your answer in a answer I'll except it.  I honestly do not understand how a debugger works to be honest with you.  I usually go to Java Visualizer online and didn't even think about that.  I also wanted to see if this was the best way to go about it too.  Also, I had a super quick question in a comment down below if you get a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with comments explaining why the final two loops are required.

```
int[] textArr = {1, 2, 3, 3, 9};
int[] binaryArr = {4, 5, 6};
int[] mergeArr = new int[textArr.length + binaryArr.length];

int i=0, j=0, k=0;
while(i < textArr.length && j < binaryArr.length) {
    if(textArr[i] < binaryArr[j]) {
        mergeArr[k] = textArr[i];
        i++;
    }
    else {
        mergeArr[k] = binaryArr[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
// At this point either i == textArr.length or j == binaryArr.length
// so you cannot do textArr[i] < binaryArr[j] without getting
// an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. 
// However the algorithm isn't finished. You still need to transfer
// the remaining numbers from one of the original arrays into the answer.
while(i < textArr.length) {
    mergeArr[k] = textArr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
while(j < binaryArr.length) {   // It said i in question. I corrected.
    mergeArr[k] = binaryArr[j];
    k++;
    j++;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mergeArr));
```

As for whether this is the most efficient code. It's about as good as you can get. Any algorithm has to read all the numbers so you can't do better than `O(n + m)` where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the original arrays. You could slightly improve performance by replacing the final `while` loops with `System.arraycopy`.

Answer (score 0):

Basic algorithm for merging two sorted arrays of size `n`. This should be enough to go off of for the more generic "merge two sorted arrays of size `m` and `n` respectively"

```
//given arrays A, B, create C
var i, j = 0, k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 2n; i++) {
  if (A[j] < B[k]) { 
    C[i] = A[j++]; 
  }
  else { 
    C[i] = B[k++];
  }
}
```

Comment: This is going to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. To avoid it you could use an approach like the one in the question.

Comment: so what exactly are the two additional while loops doing in the second part of the code I have above?  I believe you are correct Paul, I wrote something very similar and got an index out of bounds exception

Comment: Once you've used all the numbers in one of the arrays, you can no longer do the comparison `A[j] < B[k]` because an index (`j` or `k`) has moved beyond the last index. Therefore you need extra code to put the remaining numbers from the other array in the answer.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now.  In this case since every other number in each array was next in line without those two extra loops I wasn't getting the last element in the binaryArr array because it had the highest last number.  So in this case could I get rid of those two while loops and just assign the last number of binaryArr too mergeArr since I know that's what's going on?  That wouldn't be considered bad code would it?  Can I ask you one last question...why is the code above that Collin gave giving the out of bounds exception?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. You can't avoid doing something after the initial loop, because the merge isn't complete. And you can't just get the last few numbers from `binaryArr` because you don't know which array you'll need them from. I really think you should step through this with a debugger. All will become clear.

Comment: No I understand now, what I said no longer makes sense, it did when I was writing it lol.  I took out one of the two last loops because I do know which number is not getting added for this specific case.